# Store does not implement IUserRoleStore<TUser>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have my own customized Entity Store User and Entity Store Role. What I am trying now is to add user to roles. By doing this

```
public void CreateUser(RegisterBindingModel model, String roleName)
   {
        try
        {
            ApplicationRole role = null;
            if (!UserRoleManager.RoleExists(roleName))
            {
                role = new ApplicationRole() { Name = roleName, Id = Suid.NewSuid().ToString() };
                IdentityResult result = UserRoleManager.Create(role);
            }
            else
            {
                role = UserRoleManager.FindByName(roleName);
            }

            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

            IdentityResult result1 = UserManager.Create(user, model.Password);

            UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, role.Id);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message.ToString()); // I get an exception here saying, Store does not implement IUserRoleStore<TUser>
        }

  }
```

After that I implement that. I have this function now

```
    public Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(TUser user)
    {

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

How do I implement it? I mean how to I send in the roles the user have? My complete Entity user store is as follows

```
    public class EntityUserStore<TUser, TAccount> : IUserStore<TUser>, IUserPasswordStore<TUser>, IUserEmailStore<TUser> ,  IUserRoleStore<TUser>
    where TUser : class, IApplicationUser<TAccount>, new()
    where TAccount : EntityModel, new()
{
    public async Task CreateAsync(TUser user)
    {
        TableHelper.Save<TAccount>(user.Account);
        EntityIndex.Set<TAccount>(user.UserName, user.Account);
    }

    public Task DeleteAsync(TUser user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    public async Task<TUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId)
    {
        TAccount account = TableHelper.Get<TAccount>(userId);

        if (account == null)
            return null;

        return new TUser()
        {
            Account = account
        };

    }

    public async Task<TUser> FindByNameAsync(string userName)
    {
        TAccount account = EntityIndex.Get<TAccount>(userName);

        if (account == null)
            return null;

        return new TUser()
        {
            Account = account
        };
    }

    public Task UpdateAsync(TUser user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public async Task SetPasswordHashAsync(TUser user, string passwordHash)
    {
        user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;

    }

    public async Task<string> GetPasswordHashAsync(TUser user)
    {
        return user.PasswordHash;
    }

    public async Task<bool> HasPasswordAsync(TUser user)
    {
        return user.PasswordHash != null;
    }

    public async Task SetEmailAsync(TUser user, string email)
    {
        user.Email = email;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetEmailAsync(TUser user)
    {
        return user.Email;
    }

    public Task<bool> GetEmailConfirmedAsync(TUser user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task SetEmailConfirmedAsync(TUser user, bool confirmed)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public async Task<TUser> FindByEmailAsync(string email)
    {
        TAccount account = EntityIndex.Get<TAccount>(email);

        if (account == null)
            return null;

        return new TUser()
        {
            Account = account
        };
    }

    public Task AddToRoleAsync(TUser user, string roleName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task RemoveFromRoleAsync(TUser user, string roleName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(TUser user)
    {

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<bool> IsInRoleAsync(TUser user, string roleName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    } 
}
```

I am now trying this

```
    public Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(TUser user)
    {
        List<string> roles = new UserManager<TUser>(this).GetRoles(user.Id).ToList();
        return Task.FromResult((IList<string>)roles);
    }
```

But it is not working. I am getting timed out exception.

Comment: May I ask, is there a reason that you need to create your own implementation of this?  I ask, because when I first started using ASP.NET Identity, I started doing the same.  Then I realised that I could just use the implementations that already exist within the Framework and it works like a breeze.

Comment: Its been done by my boss but I think the reason is the storage mechanism. We are not using Sql but Azure.

Comment: Whether you are using Azure or not, it still requires a data store.  If it's not SQL, what is it?

Answer (score 2):

You would simply implement the following interface `IUserRoleStore<TUser>` as follows:

```
public class EntityUserStore<TUser, TAccount> : IUserStore<TUser>, 
IUserPasswordStore<TUser>, 
IUserEmailStore<TUser> ,  IUserRoleStore<TUser>, IUserRoleStore<TUser>
```

This then enforces that you implement concrete implementations of the following methods;

```
    public Task AddToRoleAsync(TUser user, string roleName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task RemoveFromRoleAsync(TUser user, string roleName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(TUser user)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task<bool> IsInRoleAsync(TUser user, string roleName)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

You would simply provide the implementation of each of the methods against your datasource.

A simplified example of the first one could be as follows (depending on your data context etc):

```
    public Task AddToRoleAsync(TUser user, string roleName)
    {
        var roleToAdd = _context.Roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == roleName);
        user.Roles.Add(roleToAdd);
        return _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

**Update**

Here is a published example from Stuart Leeks **[leeksnet.AspNet.Identity.TableStorage](https://github.com/stuartleeks/leeksnet.AspNet.Identity.TableStorage)**, this has an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Take a look at this class: [**UserStore.cs**](https://github.com/stuartleeks/leeksnet.AspNet.Identity.TableStorage/blob/master/leeksnet.AspNet.Identity.TableStorage/UserStore.cs)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I am not sure where to get _context. Also user doesn't have Roles.

Comment: Because I had  where TUser : class, IApplicationUser<TAccount>, new() and then IApplicationUser didn't had Roles defined I have now added         List<IApplicationUserRole> Roles { get; set; }. So the roles issue is gone. But still I have issues with _context. Where does that come from.

Comment: Would you not access it via the `TableHelper` in your code? The Roles property can be added to a user via `public virtual ICollection<IdentityRole> Roles { get;set;}`

Comment: I am storing roles in a static list. Which is in this class `public class EntityUserRoleStore<TRole> : IRoleStore<TRole,string>, IRoleStore<TRole>
         where TRole : class, IApplicationUserRole, new()` but I am not sure how to access it.

Comment: I was hoping I could do like this `EntityUserRoleStore<IApplicationUserRole>.roles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == roleName);` but not.

Comment: I would create a context in order to access the data, if you are using a static list you would simply use that instead of the context but that will not get back to the datasource. First thing I would do is swap out the static list of roles by pulling the data back from the db.

Comment: I am unable to use that static list. Can't figure out how to access it.

Comment: @ChaudhryMohsinAli See my update, that might help you further. It's an implementation with Azure tablestorage. Good luck. :)